# Can't select same item twice on CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

I use a `CollectionView` control to display a list of files, if users click an item a popup appears displaying information about the file and a button to download it, the problem is that I use the `SelectionChanged` method of the `CollectionView` to run this action, but if users close the popup and click again on the same item nothing happens. Back when we use `ListView` control, the `ItemTapped` event runs every time the users click the same item, but i need to changed to `CollectionView` because later we'll change the file item from a single row to multiple columns (2 or 3).

It is possible to make the users click on the same item multiple times with `CollectionView` control ?

P.D: also try to set the `SelectedItem` to null but the app crashes if the users select again the same item.

Comment: what is the exception when you set SelectedItem to null?

Comment: @Jason i'm getting a `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: which version of Forms, and which platform?  There are several existing bugs related to this.

Comment: XF version `4.6.0.800` (I think it's the last stable version right now) and both platforms Android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when i set `SelectedItem` to `null`.What else did you do when you set selectitem?

below is my simple sample,i use DisplayAlert instead of popup.

the xaml ：

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collection" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                    <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                    <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                    <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
</CollectionView>
```

in page xaml.cs:

```
private async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (collection.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");          
            collection.SelectedItem = null;

        }

    }
```

the effect is like below：

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you!!!, I've realized that never add a null check for the `SelectedItem`. I must be burn out hehe

Comment: this is not a good one, even if it's how the xamarin template goes, but when you had a lot of item, when you make the seleceteditem to null it will scroll collectionview to top which is sometimes undesirable